# Webpack - Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema

Tags: java, reactjs, spring-boot, npm, webpack

I keep getting the error thats in the title, I cant figure out why. 
"Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema."
Below is my webpack config as well as my package.json. thank you in advance!

```
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  devtool: 'sourcemaps',
  cache: true,

  mode: 'development',
  output: {
    path: __dirname,
    filename: './src/main/resources/static/built/bundle.js'
  },

  module: {
    rules: [{
        test: path.join(__dirname, '.'),
        template: 'html!' + __dirname + '/public/app/index.html',
        exclude: /(node_modules)/,
        use: [{
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"],
            plugins: ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties", {
              "loose": true
            }]

          }
        }]
      }

    ]
  }
};
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "eeareact",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.5.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.5.2",
    "rest": "^1.3.1"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "rest",
    "hateoas",
    "spring",
    "data",
    "react"
  ],
  "author": "Greg L. Turnquist",
  "license": "Apache-2.0",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/spring-guides/tut-react-and-spring-data-rest/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/spring-guides/tut-react-and-spring-data-rest",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack --watch -d",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "build-assets": "webpack -p --progress",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.1.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.1.0",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.2",
    "webpack": "^4.19.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.0"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ]
}
```

Comment: There must be some more logs in console that should give you right direction on what is wrong with the config. Based on other similar questions on Stack Overflow it points to webpack config issue.

Comment: Yes, please upload console log showing how you ran webpack and all the output webpack returned.